# XScale vs XDelta in android animation

Tags: android, xml

Am confused with XScale and XDelta

```
android:fromXDelta="0%p"
```

vs

```
android:fromXScale="1.0"
```

what are the core differences between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XScale` comes inside `<scale>` tag it is a resizing animation.

The below code is a slide down animation

```
  <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Where,

`XDelta` comes inside `<translate>` tag its is for vertical and/or horizontal motion its supports the following attributes in any of the following three formats: values from -100 to 100 ending with "%", indicating a percentage relative to itself; values from -100 to 100 ending in "%p", indicating a percentage relative to its parent; a float value with no suffix, indicating an absolute value.

The code below is a animation to move from origin to right

```
<translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
```